# How to use GREPL with string from a column like pattern in R

Tags: r, grepl

I'm working with R and i'm trying to clean my data using. I have the next data:

```
example<- data.frame(x=c("hungry","fly","day","dog"),
                        y=c("i'm hungry","i believe i can fly","a hard day's night","cat"))
```

I'm trying to identify if the Y column contains the characters from the column X. I try with grepl() but that function doesn't work with vectors and i try with `str_detect()` but i don't know why doesn't work. I finally try to get the next table:

```
      x                   y        Flag
1 hungry          i'm hungry          1
2    fly i believe i can fly          1
3    day  a hard day's night          1
4    dog                 cat          0
```

I wonder if someone can give me some option or other view to do it.

Thank!

Comment: `mapply(grepl, example$x, example$y)`

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks @Jogo!

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Vectorize` to make `grepl` vercorized, e.g.,

```
example <- within(example,Flag <- +Vectorize(grepl)(x,y))
```

such that

```
> example
       x                   y Flag
1 hungry          i'm hungry    1
2    fly i believe i can fly    1
3    day  a hard day's night    1
4    dog                 cat    0
```

Answer (score 1):

No where near as succinct as @jogo's answer but:

```
sapply(split(example, rownames(example)), 
       function(z){grepl(as.character(z$x), as.character(z$y))})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grepl` and `ifelse` in this way:

```
example$Flag <- ifelse(grepl(paste0(example$x, collapse = "|"), example$y), 1, 0)
```

Using `paste0`, this collapses `example$x` into a single pattern with alternatives separated by `|` and has `grepl` check whether the pattern complex matches the values in `example$y`: if the match is found, the `ifelse` statement assigns `1`; if it doesn't, `0`.

Alternatively, you can use `str_detect`from package `stringr`: Note that the order in which you assign the two variables to the function matters--you need to put the larger strings (i.e. those in `example$y`) first AND you need to convert both variables to character. On the upside though there's no need for the `paste0` transformation:

```
example$Flag <- ifelse(str_detect(as.character(example$y), as.character(example$x)), 1, 0)
```

Result:

```
example
       x                   y  Flag
1 hungry          i'm hungry     1
2    fly i believe i can fly     1
3    day  a hard day's night     1
4    dog                 cat     0
```